# How to change Java comments template?

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, comments, javadoc

I use /** + ENTER to generate javadoc, but i found there's a whitespace before line 3:

```
1 /**
2 * Test.
3 * 
4 * @author xxx
5 */
```

Every time i try "source - format" in eclipse,the white space comes out. How can i remove this whitespace in the comments template somewhere ?

Comment: Did you try preference->java->Code Style->Code Templates.And edit your template?

Comment: I have tried it already, but i didn't find any thing can solve the problem since there's no option about whitespace in comment settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse formatter adds space in empty comment lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008340/eclipse-formatter-adds-space-in-empty-comment-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been pissing me off for some time until I finally found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7727232/1108032). He mentions this is work around, it does not matter for me - it works like a charm. Don't forget to plus him, he is life savior!

Comment: The work around mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7727232/1108032 doesn't work if you right click on a package and execute the `Format` action.

Comment: Include answer in case link is broken.

Comment: @F.O.O This is link directlly to Stackoverflow - chances are that my answer will get deleted before the one i link to. Furthermore I deliberately link without including the answer contents - thus the updates there will immediately be reflected in my answer too, you see :)

Comment: I did think this was to an external site :D. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I have option **Blank line before Javadoc tags** in preference->Java->Code style->Formater, click on **Edit** button, open **Comments** tab and look at **Javadoc comment settings**. May be it helps you.

Comment: Thanks,but i need the blank line without a whitespace before it(Check my code you will find a whitespace after * in line 3).

Answer (score -1):

You may need to turn off Javadoc comment formatting completely.

Since Javadoc comments get turned into HTML with the default Javadoc generator/snippet, it doesn't care about extra spaces, or line breaks. One whitespace character is the same as many.

This is reflected by the Eclipse Javadoc formatter, which will treat it as a piece of markup which can be completely reformatted, so long as the output looks the same to Javadoc. I can't see any way to change the options to preserve that whitespace without turning off the formatting altogether.

Answer (score -2):

you can set it in Eclipse->preference->Java->Code style->Code Templates->Types,then you can edit it, and you can insert variables,such as date,time...

Comment: Which is the actual solution. 
@stackoverflow: Plz provide concepts against voting mobs.